# Does anyone know how to make text fade in when scrolling down, that doesn't require any plug-ins?

Tags: css

Purely just using css code on wp admin, can I make text fade in when I scroll through the page.

Comment: From my understanding this is not possible and you would need to use a javascript plugin like [ScrollMonitor](https://github.com/stutrek/scrollmonitor) to receive events when text enters or exits viewport and they fade in transition effect. Otherwise a fixed positioned element with a transparent gradient background could give reduced effect.

Comment: @Phil links to plugins aren't answers, they're recommendations, answers need to be self contained

Comment: Nathan, you should not post duplicate questions, and what you want can't be done using just CSS